# Display contents on same page javascript/ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

Thank you all for your kind help and guidance. I am trying to finish a final project and need guidance. I have all the javascript written out for the functions. I also have two html pages one for the order and two for the delivery information. The only exception is I am trying to make the contents of the order look like the assignment example per the youtube video link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Lq56ilg9U0

on 8:14-8:30 it demonstrates how the submit button is clicked then the new contents is loaded. Am I right to use iframe in order to accomplish this task or AJAX to change the contents of the page dynamically?

here is my first html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pizza Options</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Robert Elias">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pizza.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pizza.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >
<h1 style="color: gold">Welcome to Robbies Pizza Parlor</h1>
<iframe src="pizza2.html" class="iframe" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" height="600px" width="600px" >
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you use AJAX.

Comment: Either way will work. These days, AJAX is generally the preferred method.

Comment: I'll have to go ahead and agree with the above comments.

Comment: Use AJAX and you might want to look into any of the JS frameworks Backbone, React, Angular, etc

Comment: ok, if I am understanding correctly just rewrite my javascript function with AJAX method to call the information onsubmit. So in other words create a function with AJAX onsubmit to call the checkboxes that were checked and loads the new page within the parent html page per the video? Thanks again team...